# Autocomplete TextView using Google Place API

Tags: android, json, api, google-maps, autocomplete

Try to develop Android AutoComplete TextView using Google Place API, i encounter an weird error when i try my encoded URL in the browser.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=mar&types=geocode&sensor=false&key=BROWSER_KEY

{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

I try almost all the possible solution available on the web and also check in my google developer console Google Place API is enabled.

Please someone help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `BROWSER_KEY` in your URL with an actual key created in your developer console.

See: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro#Authentication

Moreover, you can access the Google Places API through the Google Play services. No need to use the a the webservice on Android. (https://developers.google.com/places/android/start)

Comment: I know that sebastian. I already replaced that with actual key and also try with android id, server id and browser id.

Comment: If you want to use the Webapi you have to use the `API key` as `BROWSWER_KEY`. Go to your developer console, select your project, `APIs & Auth`, `Credential`, `Public API access`, `Create new Key`. Assuming that you activated the `Google Places API Web Service`. This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you sebastian for quick comment. I need to activate the Google Places API Web Service but that is not free and have pricing. At the time of registration i also need to enter the company name and the domain, So if i enable the Google Place API for Android and generate the browser key then it works or not.

Comment: You are allowed to do 1000 request per day for free. https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage

Comment: hello sebastian please look at the screenshot         https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wpvjbrdr82rcde/Screenshot%202015-05-17%2003.33.49.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you building a webservice or an Android app? If you are building an Android app just use 'Google places API for Android' through 'Google Play Services'.

Comment: Thank you sebastian now its working, i think it is little bit confusing because in the old google developer console it shows pricing for the google place api web services and on the new google developer console it is totally free. So as suggested by you after enabling the web services it is working now.

Comment: I developed an android app but i think only enabling the google place api for android doesn't work and we also need to enable the google place api for webservices

Comment: Enabling "Places API for Android" in the developer console allows you to use the new Android API, which was released in March: https://developers.google.com/places/android/

Your current implementation relies on the Places API Web Service, which requires enabling "Places API Web Service" in the developer console.